# Integrating using polar co-ordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Hey I've just finished an exam paper and just am stuck with one question.
It's something that usually makes sense to me but for some reason I can't get this one:

> Let $R = \{(x,y) : x,y ≥ 0, x^2 + y^2 \le 4\} $, which is a circular sector in the ﬁrst quadrant. Use polar coordinates to evaluate $$\iint_R (x^2 + y^2)e^{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} dA.$$

What I've done is $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, so $r = 2$.

since $x, y \ge 0$ then our limits will be $[0, \pi]$

$$\ \int^\pi_0 \int^2_0 r^2e^{r^4}\ dr\ d\theta$$
We substitute $u= r^2, du=2rdr, dr = \frac 1 2 rdu$ to get

$$\int^\pi_0 \int^2_0 ue^{u^2} \frac1 {2\sqrt u}dud\theta $$

Then I'm stuck I think I've gone wrong somewhere with the u's but I'm not sure.
any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the translation include an extra $r$ term?  Like $\text dx\text dy\to r\text dr\text d\theta$...

Comment: Your limit of integration for theta should be [0, $/pi$/2] and you should definitely have a trig function of theta in your Integrand. Also, just because there's a 4 in your exponent doesn't mean you can substitute it in terms of r.

Comment: Putting together the correct and relevant parts of the previous comments: $dA$ in polar coordinates is always $r\,dr\,d\theta$ (which makes the integral much easier!), and your limits of integration for $\theta$ are incorrect. There will not be a trig function in your integrand, and the $r^4$ in your exponent is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1)since you are in the first quadrant the limits of $\theta$ are $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

2) the area element in polar coordinates is $da=rdr d\theta$

so your integral becomes:

$$
\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^2 r^3e^{r^4}drd\theta
$$

3) use the substitution: $r^4=t$